# Python's time.sleep() hangs

Tags: python, sleep

I have a test script that sleeps for a random amount of seconds, between 1 and 180 seconds.  The test program would hang for more than 3 minutes.

So I changed the code so that it would sleep for 60 seconds (1 minute) and ran the script.  After 20 hours (!!!), the code is still hanging on time.sleep().

The code is

```
downtime = 60
time.sleep(downtime)
```

Why does Python hang forever on a time.sleep(60)?

Comment: is this the whole script ? if not, can you post it here ?

Comment: What would be supposed to happen after the sleep ends? (i.e., how can you know sleep have not finished long ago?)

Comment: Probably because `downTime` is set to a large number.

Comment: Your example here has `downtime` spelled two different ways.  If this is actually from your code, there's your problem.  If this *isn't* actually from your code, maybe you could post your actual code and we can try to help out.

Comment: You have "downtime" and "downTime" - is that correct?

Comment: Oops, my code posting was incorrect.  Both are using the variable "downTime"

Comment: Did you resolve this? Are you using multiple threads with `threading`? I have such a script that is hanging, and time.sleep() is a possible culprit.. Incidentally, when it hangs, registered `signal` handlers are not fired either ):

Comment: My problem was a `Lock` acquired twice in the same thread - using `RLock` instead fixed it. The signal handlers weren't fired because the problem was in the main thread (bad idea!) - my main thread now has a trivial `for` loop and the signal handlers always fire (:

Comment: Is this tho whole code? Any multithreading/muptiproxessing/greenlets?

Answer (score 5):

You use 2 different variables *downtime* and *downTime*. Probably, *downTime* greater than 60

Answer (score 5):

It is dark under the lamp.
The reason could be ridiculous.

Check if you ever clicked the shell screen.

[Processes running on Powershell freezes randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676635/processes-running-on-powershell-freezes-randomly/39676636#39676636)

Comment: Dude, thank you. Found this just before embarking on a journey to discover why sleep() was hanging forever.

Comment: Perfect! I have a Python script with a periodic `sleep` running on my son's computer and couldn't figure out why it kept freezing. Turns out he was clicking in the shell :)

Answer (score 4):

Even though `time.sleep()` is permitted to suspend your thread for an interval that is shorter, or longer, than what you ask, `time.sleep(60)` would not suspend your thread for 20 hours.

I can see several possible explanations:

1. You are calling `time.sleep()` multiple times (e.g. in a loop).
2. You are calling `time.sleep()` with an argument that is much higher than 60 (note the two different ways you're spelling `downtime`/`downTime` in your code).
3. The problem has nothing to do with `time.sleep()`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had commented some lines and introduced a bug due to a missing variable. For example:

```py
# Some_code...
# my_var = True
time.sleep(1)
return my_var
```

This was not a hang due to `sleep()` but rather an error that was occurring in the worker nodes and the master node never got a response, waiting for a result that was never going to arrive. Checking the logs of the workers I could see the error and correct it.