# A process running on Powershell freezes randomly

Tags: powershell

I'm running Node.js server with **Powershell**. My server **stops working randomly**, for a reason that I do not know.

I've googled `Node.js stops working randomly`, `ExpressJS stops working randomly`, etc. hundreds of times and injected debugging code stuff to my Node.js code in order to fix it.

But I **cannot prevent it**, I cannot! What's wrong with my server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In fact, it is not because of Node.js, but **because of Powershell's QuickEdit feature**.

With Powershell's QuickEdit, you can easily mark some text by just dragging it.
... and your **process(script) working on the shell freezes when you're marking some text**.

You can disable it by:

1. Right-click the title bar of the Powershell window and click `Properties`.
2. Uncheck `QuickEdit Mode` on the `Options` tab.

**What I did for weeks was a complete waste of time!**

Comment: *What I’ve been doing